# Angular Js Limit digits after/before decimal point

Tags: angularjs

I am using custom directive to limit user to three numbers before decimal and two number after decimal

My directive

```
module.directive('decimalPlaces', function() {
                return {
                    link : function(scope, ele) {
                        ele.bind('keypress', function(e) {
                            var newVal = $(this).val() + (e.charCode !== 0 ? String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) : '');
                            if (!(/^\d{1,3}(\.$|\.\d{1,2}$|$)/).test(newVal)) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
            });
```

But when i use backspace before decimal and completely clear , then i am unable to enter again.

I need to delete it completely, is there any specific regex pattern for that.

For example at first i enter 125.45

Then before decimal i backspace and make it .45, then i am unable to add any numbers before .45

Considering points

1. only three digits ( max) before decimal
2. only two digits ( max) after decimal
3. if user puts only 20 without float , like 20 it should appear as 20.00

Comment: Explain more as list of points that you are going to consider

Comment: Mr_perfect, i have added points

Comment: Add HTML code of the input to which you are applying this directive

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression

```
if (!(/^\d{0,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$/).test(newVal)) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

And the formatting as you said, if `20` is the value and `20.00` should appear, you must do

Comment: Yes but using above regex i am unable to enter any decimals . like 125.34

Comment: Have you observed the update `{0,3}` instead of `{1, 3}`?

Comment: Yes i have taken that update into account, but still i am not able to enter

Comment: Just check here https://www.debuggex.com/ with regular expression `^\d{0,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$`. It's working

Comment: Regular expression will work. But the error part is somewhere else in the code

Comment: Console log the `newValue` inside the condition

Comment: yes i have tried it printing 125. or 1253 when i tried to enter 125.34

Comment: i think (e.charCode !== 0 ? String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) : ''); creating problem

Comment: on keypress you are getting value by `$(this).val()`. Instead of that, use `ng-model` of the input